# VBA Excel: Findnext is looping & returning cells that do not contain the search string

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, find

The code finds the cell with "Balance" in it and saves the cell to a variable, `foundcell`, in order to find the balance column on the spreadsheet.  There are multiple balance columns.  I tested this with just the `FIND` and it worked by finding the first column with "Balance" in D8.

Once I added the loop for the `findnext`, it returns D8, G8, H8, I8 and A9, then crashes because A9 is wrong. `FINDNEXT` should only return I8 and stop, given there are 2 cells in the search range with the word "balance.   G8, H8, and A9 do not contain the word "balance".

```
    Sub ReFill_Credit()
' Macro - ReFill formula columns for Credit sheet
'https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/21/find-all-instances-with-vba

Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim FindString As String
Dim foundcell As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastRow1 As Integer
Dim CopyCell As Range
Dim endcell As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim Lastcell As Range
Dim coloffset As Integer
Dim cellofffset As Range
Dim colbal As Integer

With Sheets("Credit")

'citi = 4 '"d"
'chase = 9 '"i"
'colbal = citi
FindString = "Balance"

Set SrchRng = .Range("a1:k15")
Set Lastcell = SrchRng.Cells(SrchRng.Cells.Count)

'Find the Balance cell
Set foundcell = SrchRng.Find(What:=FindString, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False)
Debug.Print ""

'Test to see if anything was found
If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then
    firstaddress = foundcell.Address
 'end If
 Debug.Print "firstaddress = " & firstaddress

'Loop to next "balance" column ***************************************************
Do
    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print "**********starting 'do until'*********"
    Debug.Print "foundcell (1st search) is: " & foundcell.Address

'Test if cycled thru back to the first cell
    StartRow = foundcell.Row + 1
    Debug.Print "startrow is  " & StartRow
    colbal = foundcell.Column
    FirstCell = Cells(StartRow, colbal)

'Finds the last non-blank cell on a sheet/range.
    coloffset = colbal - 1
    'Debug.Print "colbal is:  " & colbal
    Debug.Print "coloffset is:  " & coloffset

    LastRow = .Columns(coloffset).Find(What:="*", _
                 LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                 MatchCase:=False).Row
    Debug.Print "last row is  " & LastRow
    LastRow1 = LastRow + 1

'Fill formula down COL D
    Set CopyCell = .Cells(StartRow, colbal)
    Set endcell = .Cells(LastRow1, colbal)
    Debug.Print "copycell = " & CopyCell
    Debug.Print "copycell.add = " & CopyCell.Address
    Debug.Print "endcell is  " & endcell.Address
'=IF(ISTEXT(D8),D$7,D8)+C9 / starting at d9
    CopyCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=.Range(CopyCell, endcell),     Type:=xlFillValues
    Debug.Print "findstring is " & FindString

'Find next *********************************************************
    Set foundcell = SrchRng.FindNext(foundcell)
 '       If foundcell.Address = firstfound Then Exit Do
Loop While Not foundcell Is Nothing And foundcell.Address <> firstaddress

End If
End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: It appears your `.FindNext` is using the criteria from your last `.Find`. Specifically, `What:="*"`

Comment: Thanks.. I think you're right.  I stared at that all day and never saw it.  How do i work around that?  The second find (find last row) is based off the first find.  Findnext should be based on the first find as well.

Comment: Use `.Find` instead of `.FindNext`.

Answer (score 1):

I swapped out the block that calculated the LastRow using `FIND`:

```
    LastRow = .Columns(coloffset).Find(What:="*", _
             LookAt:=xlPart, _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
             MatchCase:=False).Row
```

with this instead:

```
LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, coloffset).End(xlUp).Row
```

Hopefully this method is identical to the previous method and has no unforeseen problems.